# Распараллеливание потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

как сделать чтобы потоки(последовательность не важна), каждую секунду выводили надпись? Важно чтобы отработала синхронизация, чтобы один поток зашел в тело метода, а другие ждали, выполнил, потом другой рандомный поток так же зашел выполнил, а все другие опять же ждали... вот по такому примеру

```
public class qq {
    public static void main (  String [] args ) throws UnknownHostException, InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            new The().start();
        }
    }

    public static class The extends Thread {

        final Counter c = new Counter();

        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            while (true) {
                c.c();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Counter{

        public synchronized void c(){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("qq");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше решение не будет работать правильно, потому что каждый поток вызывает свой метод `run`. Из за этого синхронизация не будет работать так, как ожидается. Самый простой способ - создать статический метод и сделать его синхронизированным, либо в каждый поток передать один и тот же объект у которого будет синхронизированный метод.

Пример первого подхода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                    greeter();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }


    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){}
}

private static synchronized void greeter(){
    System.out.println("hello "+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Добиться блокирования потоков, так же возможно при помощи инструментов синхронизации из пакета `java.util.concurrent`, например `ReentrantLock`, `Semaphore`

Comment: О боги! вы меня спасли, я пытался лишь понять почему доступ имеют много потоков, static мне очень помог, не ожидал что из-за такой глупости все пойдет на перекосяк.. спасибо большое)

Comment: Да не за что ))